# HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions on calling session.update()

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a table which is associated with many other tables either with one to one or one to many relationships. While updating these tables with `session.update(Parent_Table)`, I get the following exception.

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Update Method:

```
public static String update(ParentTable table)  throws Exception {      
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(table);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return success;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return failure;
    }
}
```

Here I am adding new child records and making them associated with parent table or modifying existing parent or child record and passing the parent table to `session.update(table)`.

No clue how two different sessions are getting created. Even though I close existing sessions before update statement and open a new session, getting the same exception.

Could anybody suggest what might be going wrong here?

Comment: The exception suggests that a collection contained inside the object graph of parenttable is already associated with another hibernate sessio. Obvious conclusion parenttable was read by another session. Try searching the message on SO or google. In SO it brings 49 results. Did you take a look at them?

Comment: @ nakosspy, I have gone through most of the cases in SO where right answer is being selected. Nothing seems to be relevant to my case.

Comment: OK, are you sure that the session you used to read the table object is not open?

Comment: The operation I am trying to do is update in the session obtained through getCurrentSession(). Even I have tried killing all opened sessions and created a new session before update but the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

What frameworks and container you are use? what versions?

you use something like this?:

```
 <filter>
  <filter-name>OSIV</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>OSIV</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

spring-jpa-config.xml

```
<bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

you use @Transactional? - also can create new session.

Comment: How are you configuring the SessionFactory itself?